# Como guardar ROLES en base de datos Symfony

Tags: symfony4

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en symfony, y he hecho un formulario de registro y login, y la verdad es que funciona, pero el registro me pone el campo `roles` de la base de datos así: `[]` Y si quiero tener un acces control como este en el `security.yml`

`- { path: ^/creator, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }`

No sé como poner ese ROLE_ADMIN en la base de datos pues es una columna tipo json y no sé como guardarle los roles.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero creo que lo que quieres hacer es colocarle a la ruta creator el ROLE_ADMIN

Esto se hace en el archivo security.yml si usas Symfony 3 o inferiores.

Si usas Symfony 4 viene en security.yaml

La documentación acerca de los roles la encuentas aquí: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Si lo que quieres es colocarle al usuario un rol, debes crear en la entidad un campo para almacenar dichos roles.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles

Y estas son las opciones de configuración del archivo security: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Un abrazo.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, lo que quería saber es el cómo se guarda el campo roles en la base de datos para que lo coja así que en el controlador del registro añadí: `$roles = [];` `$roles[] = "ROLE_ADMIN"; `$user->setRoles($roles);` y me guardó la columna `roles` así:  `["ROLE_ADMIN"]` y funciona correctamente para el control de acceso.